# Eevee hair particles are not rendered properly in the final render

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to create this bedroom scene using Eevee. As you can see in the image below, the carpet looked fine in the Eevee viewport, however, it looked very strange in the final render. Anyone knows what was the cause of this issue? Thanks.

[image]

[image]